# AS2: a message with fadeout with _alpha > 100

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, alpha

I'm using Action Script 2 (in Adobe Flash).

I want to show a text message in screen. I need to show it for 2sec. and then fade it out during 1 sec.

I'm trying to use AS2 instead of traditional timeline. ( because it gives me power of changing anything later with just changing some Numbers and I need it)

So my textbox have two period :

1. _alpha=100 ( 2sec)
2. _alpha decreasing in 1sec till _alpha=0

In first I implemented it with two timers.

Then I came up with a tricky idea to use just one timer. That is, **I first set _alpha to 300 and then decrease it 10(value) every 100ms.**

Question : **Will this idea make problem for me later ? ( is setting _alpha 300 reliable ?)**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Greensock tweening librairies](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) , its really simple to use and very powerfull.

Exemple :

```
import com.greensock.*
TweenMax.to(yourtextboxinstance, 1, {_alpha:0, delay:2});
```

It will wait for 2 sec, then tween "yourtextboxinstance" from alpha 100 to 0 in 1 seconde.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a try for my next projects.